# How to get month and year from the date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

Date like `20120101, 20120201, 20120301...`

Fomat is `yyyymmdd`

I want to display month and year from the date like 01/2012, 02/2012, 03/2012...

Expected Output

```
01/2012
02/2012
03/2012
```

I don't want `1/2012, 2/2012, 3/2012...`

Can any one give me a idea or query help....

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions about the same data set and the same table, so in addition to marc_s's useful answer, it's worth noting that this is yet another case where a calendar table could be helpful for you. If you add a column called `YYYYMMDD_Date` and one called `Period` (as you called it another question) then you can query and join on values directly, which is often easier and faster then using a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(20) 
SET @input = '20120101'

-- convert the 20120101 to a DATETIME    
DECLARE @thedate DATETIME
SELECT @thedate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @input, 112)

-- reformat that DATETIME to your needs    
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(20)

SET @output = RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, @thedate) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + 
              '/' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @thedate) AS VARCHAR(4))

SELECT @output
```

You could "hide" this functionality into a user-defined function to make it more easily usable in your code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MonthYearFromDate (@input VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @thedate DATETIME
    SELECT @thedate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @input, 112)

    DECLARE @output VARCHAR(20)
    SET @output = RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, @thedate) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @thedate) AS VARCHAR(4))

    RETURN @output
END
```

and then you can call this like so:

```
SELECT dbo.MonthYearFromDate('20120515')
```

and get the output

```
05/2012
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(datepart(month,getdate()) AS CHAR)  + '/' + CAST(datepart(year,getdate()) AS CHAR)
```

Instead of the function getdate() you need your date field.

Comment: **Getting error:** Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 - Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '/' to data type int. `DATEPART` returns an `INT` - you cannot just concat `INT` and a string literal `/` without using CAST or CONVERT ....

Comment: Using `CAST(... AS CHAR)` (without specifying a length) turns both month and year into **30 character, fixed-width** strings ..... not exactly what you want. Also: for the month of May, you get `5` as the month output - not `05` as the OP expects ...

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the SUBSTRING function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

You should also consider storing your dates as a DATETIME (I assume you are using VARCHAR?)

Answer (score 0):

Search on extract() function. It will solve your problem.

Comment: How? What is the `extract()` function? Can you show an example how to use it? A link to its documentation? I'm not familiar with any `extract()` function in SQL Server's T-SQL language ....